# How to get value on <a> when click

Tags: javascript, jquery

my HTML

```
<a href="#" class="my_button" value="red">Red: Fire</a>
<a href="#" class="my_button" value="blue">Blue: Water</a>
<a href="#" class="my_button" value="green">Green: Earth</a>
```

my JS

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my_button').click(function() {
        var code = $(this).val();
        alert(code);
    });
});
```

how to get the result like when I click `Red: Fire` it will alert `red` and etc...

please help me

Comment: That is not a right attribute for an anchor tag, you might consider using `data-*`

Answer (score 1):

You better use the `data` attribute.

Try this

```
<a href="#" class="my_button" data-value="red">Red: Fire</a>
<a href="#" class="my_button" data-value="blue">Blue: Water</a>
<a href="#" class="my_button" data-value="green">Green: Earth</a>
```

and in your JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my_button').click(function() {
    var code = $(this).data('value');
    alert(code);
});
```

Comment: This is the correct approach if your NEED it to be an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$('.my_button').click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).html()));
});
```

Below, I have a snippet you can run to check it out.

```js
$(function(){
  
    // The binding should happen after 
    // the document is ready.
    $('.my_button').click(function() {
        alert(alert($(this).html()));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="my_button" value="red">Red: Fire</a>
<a href="#" class="my_button" value="blue">Blue: Water</a>
<a href="#" class="my_button" value="green">Green: Earth</a>
```

Comment: I think yours is the simplest solution to what the question asks, though in better practice as other guys have stated, he might need to consider using the data attribute.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/kmaqg3cy/

Here is the correct answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my_button').click(function() {
        var code = $(this).attr('data');
        alert(code);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$(this).attr("value");
```

here's a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3dvgrbp4/

in a second a lot more similar answers landed, all revolving around the same, pasting a snippet to show a difference between prop vs attr

```
$(elem).attr('checked')    // returned true (Boolean) prior to 1.6
$(elem).attr('checked')   // now returns "checked" (string) 1.6
$(elem).prop('checked')    // now returns true (Boolean) 1.6
```

but as others mentioned better to move to *data* attribute since *value* is not a valid property for the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('.my_button').unbind('click').click(function() {
        var code = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(code);
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="my_button" value="red">Red: Fire</a>
<a href="#" class="my_button" value="blue">Blue: Water</a>
<a href="#" class="my_button" value="green">Green: Earth</a>
```

Tag  doesn't has `value` as property but it has `value` as attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `<button>` tag instead. `<a>` tags do not have a value attribute.  I would use the button tag unless you needed it to be a hyperlink.  In that case use the data- approach mentioned by su8898.  Your class says it's a button, the functionality says it's a button (no location for the href), it should be a button :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var code = $(this).attr("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my_button').click(function() {
        var code = $(this).attr('data');
        alert(code);
    });
});
```

Comment: I suggest you add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better.